# Bypass Battery Saver Limitation for Android Push Notification

Tags: android, push-notification

I just developed an android chat application for private community and face problem with notification didn't work. I read some article mentioned that delayed push notificatian were mostly caused by battery saver setting being turned on. But then why whatsapp push notification can still work with battery saver on? Is there anyway to automatically whitelist my application so it can receive notification any time?

Comment: after marshamllow did you checked app permition in seting

Comment: seems like the trouble is on the server side,, we use applozic messaging servic,es, so we cannot sure. but i 'd checked my code and it seems okay. the real problem is the message delayed and need me to open the apps to force it synchronize all message, so i'm afraid applozic server didn't push the message to the client app, and that's why i got no notification. omg

Comment: Have  you done gcm/fcm  push notification setup from this link https://www.applozic.com/docs/android-chat-sdk.html#step-4-push-notification-setup and updated the gcm/fcm server key in applozic dashboard under the push notification tab  ?

Comment: Yes, we did... Unless we wouldn't received any push notification at all. The problem here is the message notification is delayed. But it looks like it working. Say, i sent message on 9:00am then my user receive a push notification on 11:00am. So it's look like working but very slow.

But if my user opened the application as soon as after I send the message, all message then got pushed and they received many notification at same time.

Comment: @GuyFreakz Can you send applicationKey, userId and  your app android manifest file to support@applozic.com .if you sample project where i can check this problem  send that also or an debug apk  ..that will be helpful for us to debug